# Can't ReWrite when migrate Apache to nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, php

I want to change one of my server Apache to `nginx+php-fpm` but there is a little problem that using rewrite. Requests come like this `/dispatcher.php/foo/foo/foo/1`

I couldn't decide how can i send this request to `php-fpm` because when I send this request to `php-fpm` i get not found error. There is no file or path like this but i must send whole url like this and dispatcher.php get and process this url.

Comment: What does your rewrite look like?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a location block like so:

```
location /dispatcher.php/ {
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/dispatcher.php;
  #rest of your fastcgi bits go here
}
```

to your fastcgi directives (obviously replacing the path to point to your actual dispatcher.php location)